# Interruption of stay in Germany with EU Blue card

Tags: europe

I have a query regarding validity of blue card inspite of a period of absence from Germany. Due to a medical emergency I have to stay in India for next 6 7 months. Will my blue card remain valid if I leave my employment and deregister from the city? I emailed foreign office they replied it is valid for 1 year even if I am outside EU, but under conditions. I am not sure about the condition part. If anyone can shed light on the matter, it would be great. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Debaditya Roy what happened next ?

Comment: Well my company deputed me to India allowing me to keep the job. I am earning an d paying my taxes in Germany by signing an Indo German social security agreement, that was procured by the insurance firm on discussion with my company.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The foriegn office is quoting §51 (10) (1) AufenthG: 12 months

- which overrides §51 (1) (7) AufenthG : 6 months

this goes on to say, any **longer** period must be cleared with the local Arbeitsamt.
(This is the only other condition in that paragraph, so I assume that is what they mean)

To be save, report the situation to the Arbeitsamt (case manager Sachbearbeiter) and in case of any **delays** inform them of the delay which they should confirm in writing.